# fetch throws in console even though there is try{}catch(){}

Tags: reactjs, http, error-handling, react-redux, fetch

Does anyone know why I can't handle server error with try{}catch(){}?
There is a console error although I am trying to handle fetch errors within the fetch context and outside of it?

Please refer to the attached image to get a better understanding: [Fetch request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SF8jf.png)

I am using react with redux-saga but I think there is nothing related with redux.

I tried executing that same function in the component itself and it still happens.